# Magic 7F45 error when running NDK executable on android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I created a simple Hello World C program, compiled it using ndk-build, and transferred it via adb. Essentially I followed the steps in http://d34th4ck3r.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/how-to-run-c-cpp-code-in-android/ except for the GNUmake step (it didn't seem necessary as I still got my binary file).

However, when I run it, I first got a "can't execute: Permission denied" error. After using chmod 777, I got a "not executable: magic 7F45" error.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: In this case this message should be interpreted as "in spite of having the correct 7F45 magic, this file is not an executable". There may be a lot of causes, incompatible ABI (e.g. Compiled for ARMv7-a, launched on ARMv6) being one. Which device did you use? Where did you push your binary?