# How to do a cross compilation to avoid "magic 7F45" error

Tags: android, arm, cross-compiling

I want to use the Android Screenshot Library. In order to start the native service, i have to execute the run.ps1 file via Windows PowerShell, as it's written here: https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/UserGuide
I got the "..asl-native : not executable : magic 7F45" error, and i read that i have to make a cross-compilation to make it work; but i have no clue how to do that? what compilers should I use?

Comment: I think this should help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314277/magic-7f45-error-when-running-ndk-executable-on-android

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) , but it doesn't really help. I still don't know what compilers to use.

Answer (score 3):

Magic number 7F45 specifies the Executable and Linkable Format (ELF) file type, a format that is not executable on ARM processors.

Reason could be either improper cross compilation or either using wrong toolchain.

Using correct toolchain should fix this problem

Comment: This is exactly the problem. What toolchain should I use, please?